# Server access.log is flooded by requests with referrer m.facebook

Tags: facebook, nginx, google-analytics, flooding

When analyzing my nginx access.log on my linux server i found, that there are tons of requests made by mobile devices with referrer m.facebook.com..

But there are not that many visitors on my site (according to google analytics)..

Does anyone know where this requests come from and why they are not logged in analytics?

This is one entry in the access.log which seems to be suspicious:

```
xx.xx.x.xxx - - [11/Aug/2016:15:51:20 +0200] "GET /skimagazin/wintereinbruch-in-den-hochlagen-oesterreichs-und-deutschlands.htm HTTP/2.0" 200 12445 "http://m.facebook.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; SM-G800F Build/LMY47X; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/52.0.2743.98 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/89.0.0.17.70;]"
```

Comment: Same hapenned with us. It seems that is a headless browser (that doesn't run javascript) makes those request. That's why it's not registered in Google Analytics. The question is, why is facebook doing this? Seems like, for every "facebook ad" displayed there is one request happening.